# How would I deploy new pod to a dedicated node in kubernetes cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks

I am designing an app where user submits a file, which will be processed on a pod and will return back the details via rest api call. I have been using AWS and will user EKS for this. The flow is somewhat:

> `File Uploaded -> Added to Docker Container while build and pushed to
>   registry -> Kube API will create a new node and run the pod in that
>   node -> After scanning, return back the results to server using Auth
>   Headers -> Drop node from cluster`

I started using EKS along with Cloudformation but had to give hard coded values of scaling, but this app can have nodes ranging from 1 - 100. And, I am not able to understand how to add or remove nodes from Cloudformation and EKS via SDK. I am currently using eksctl.

Comment: The eksworkshop has some good information about the cluster autoscaler: https://eksworkshop.com/scaling/deploy_ca/

Comment: @jontro This doc explains with fixed number of scaling.

Comment: Well, you can use the cluster autoscaler in combination with node anti affinity and it would automatically scale up a new node if the pod cannot be scheduled

Comment: @jontro 
Thanks for Prompt reply! 
Also, will this stop and delete the node when pod execution is over?

Comment: Check the faq here, it will shut a node down once certain requirements are met https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md